# Re-targeting Users That Clicked a Link In An Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email

I'm currently trying to create a list of contacts that have clicked a specific link within an email so that I can retarget them with another email.

My issue is that when I go onto the click activity -> Link View -> Unique Clicks -> Copy all

Then I copy all the contacts to a list and end up with some contacts missing the first name. I'm unsure why this is happening.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Click](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) data view.

Your query will look something like this:

```
select 
SubscriberID,
SubscriberKey,
LinkName,
URL,
TriggeredSendCustomerKey
from [_Click]
where isUnique = 1 and 
jobid = 'the job id of the email send' (if guided send)
//TriggeredSendCustomerKey = 'the trigger send customer key' (if journey builder send)
```

Once, you have this information you can join this with your master table and join on Subscriberkey to get other information like First Name